# IndexOutOfBoundsException when clicking on FAB with EditText on Oreo

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I get a "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" error thrown when a user clicks on a FAB to add a timer or clicks on a number button on a TimerEditActivity. This happens exclusively on Android 8.0. I tried different approaches, but don't know really how to fix this.

```
void onClick(TextView view) {
        if (mFocusGrabber.isFocused())
            return;
        EditText field = getFocusedField();
        int at = field.getSelectionStart();
        field.getText().replace(at, at + 1, view.getText()); //LINE 116, causing the error
        field.setSelection(at + 1);
//        updateStartButtonVisibility();
        if (field.getSelectionStart() == FIELD_LENGTH) {
            // At the end of the current field, so try to focus to the next field.
            // The search will return null if no view can be focused next.
            View next = field.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            if (next != null) {
                next.requestFocus();
                if (next instanceof EditText) {
                    // Should always start off at the beginning of the field
                    ((EditText) next).setSelection(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the stacktrace from Play Console. Line 116 seems to be the culprit.

```
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1309)
      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:510)
      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:504)

      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:502)
      at be.demillennial.oneclock.timers.EditTimerActivity.onClick (EditTimerActivity.java:116)

      at be.demillennial.oneclock.timers.EditTimerActivity$$ViewBinder$7.doClick (EditTimerActivity$$ViewBinder.java:92)
      at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick (DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
      at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6891)
      at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:12651)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:26083)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: The error is thrown by this line `field.getText().replace(at, at + 1, view.getText());` which mean either `at` or `at+1` is to big or to low to be a correct index. I think it's `at+1` that is too big when the user select the last character of the field, then `at+1` is out of the field and give you an exception. You need to add a if condition to check if `at+1` is in the range or not before calling `replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is bound to crash if your selection is at the end

```
field.getText().replace(at, at + 1, view.getText());
```

If you have 6 characters in edit text, you can not replace values between 6-7. It will always through IndexOutOfBoundsException

Put a check like you did in the next line and it wont crash

```
if (field.getSelectionStart() <= FIELD_LENGTH) {
```

Comment: Thank you! But had to alter your solution a bit. Had to check the if condition with <=

Comment: Oh yeah sorry i forgot that :p